# I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on an old laptop in place of Windows 8.1, and now it won't boot

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uefi

I have an old laptop with a broken screen that I'm trying to set up to stream sports games to my TV with, and I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it from USB. I went through the installation and everything went well. I opted to "Erase everything and install Ubuntu". As I said, the computer's old, so there's nothing important on it.

After installation, I restart. If I leave the USB in, I get the grub screen, and the options are only to

- try ubuntu without installing
- install ubuntu
- OEM install
- check disk for defects.

If I remove the USB and restart, I get a screen that says:

```
failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi
failed to load image
failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi
failed to load image
```

After that it loads what looks like a boot menu with the option to boot from HDD, CD, or LAN, or open the BIOS. Choosing HDD starts goes to the "failed to open.." screen for a second then back to the boot menu.

In the BIOS, very few options are available. For example, there's no option to turn off secure boot.

Not knowing what else to do, I put in the USB and selected "Try Ubuntu without Installing" then installed an ran boot-repair. On reboot, nothing changed. The link boot-repair gave me is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10828349/

If anyone has any thoughts on what I need to do or any leads on resources I can read up on in order to figure this out, I'd greatly appreciate it. I feel like I've googled everything possible trying to research it and I've come to a bit of a dead end.

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resources http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295 
You have got a Lenovo model try to find a post about.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer shipped with Windows 8 or 8.1 and has a Windows sticker on it, the contract between the manufacturer and Microsoft ***requires*** that you be able to disable Secure Boot. There's no requirement that you be able to do this in any particular way, so you may need to check your menus very carefully. The option might not even mention "Secure Boot" by name; it could be "Boot Mode" with options of "Windows OS" and "Other," or something equally nondescript, or even outright deceptive. I've seen a few people suggest that Secure Boot can be disabled only if BIOS/CSM/legacy support is enabled on some systems, although I've never seen this linkage myself.

The fact that I just wrote a paragraph about this should make you think that I'm suggesting you disable Secure Boot. If you came to this conclusion, you're correct; your symptoms are consistent with a Secure Boot bug that causes Secure Boot to not accept the signature on your copy of Shim. Your symptoms are also consistent with a Shim that's mis-matched to your GRUB and MokManager binaries. This should not happen if you installed Ubuntu from scratch on a clean disk, but it might happen if you fiddled with the binaries after the fact or if you had an existing `EFI/ubuntu` directory on your ESP when you began.

If disabling Secure Boot doesn't help, try installing a different Shim binary, along with its matchin `MokManager.efi` binary. [This version](http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/shim-signed/) is old but has worked for me on one system that's finicky about its Secure Boot signatures. Note that if you install a non-Ubuntu Shim, you'll need to enroll Canonical's certificate using the MokManager utility. (It should pop up automatically, provided you installed the `MokManager.efi` that matches your `shimx64.efi`.) It's available in an Ubuntu package, but I don't recall which one offhand. I've collected several in the rEFInd package; see [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/keys/) for download links to them all. You want `canonical-uefi-ca.der`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll be working on this in the morning using your advice about Secure Boot as a guide and report back.